# How to detect if static constructor was executed in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, static-constructor

I'm testing complex .net/COM application under Intel Inspector (native memory leaks). In quite a few places in .net code we are caching references to COM objects in static fields. Obviously Inspector is flagging those as leaks. In a few cases adding suppressions is sufficient, however sometimes number of objects that are flagged (created as part of the main COM object) is out of control (hundreds) and suppressing those may hide similar patterns that are actual leaks.
Making long story short - just before process exits I'm iterating over all classes in all assemblies loaded in the appdomain, and I'm setting to null static fields that are referencing my COM objects. It would be great for future usage if I could print all static fields referencing COM objects even if they were not yet accepted as valid caches (and may be actual leaks).

However if type was never used, it's static constructor will execute when I'm calling getField (to see if it is null) and may create more COM objects.
Is there any way to detect if type was ever used in current AppDomain?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do it automatically, but you could have the static constructors register themselves. So instead of iterating over all classes in the assembly, you iterate over all registered classes.

```
public static class ClassRegistrar
{
    private static List<Type> registered = new List<Type>();
    public static void Register(Type type)
    {
        registered.Add(type);
    }
    public static IEnumerable<Type> Registered
    { get { return registered; } }
}

public class MyClass
{
    static MyClass()
    {
        ClassRegistrar.Register(typeof(MyClass));
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is no go for me. I can't change production code only for sake of this one test. Secondly static constructor is actually generated by compiler when in our F# code we create bindings. So doing the registration would require changing a lot of classes and would require change each type somebody adds new module/class with binding.

Comment: Well, the short answer is that you cannot do what you want to do. If you provide some sample code (even in F#), I am sure that it will either reveal an architectural shortcoming or a way to work around it.

Comment: Philip, I think my first point says it all - this is just test and it does not justify changing 1000+ projects in order to register class instantiation. If it comes to worst I will need to just hand craft my code based on manual debugging investigations (when Inspector flags a leak track down what class holds reference to it).

Comment: I wonder if debugging api would be able to provide information I need. I fully understand it would be overkill